# How to embedd different websites on the same HTML page depending on the element you are comming from

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sorry the title sounds pretty bulky, but maybe it clears up. So I have this website. On one HTML I have a long list of containers that show different leisure activity programs. Each of these containers is equipped with a button that leads to another HTML. On that side, the respective website to the activity shall be embedded in a window. So I want to show the website of the respective element on this other HTML page, the thing is, there are other functionalities on the HTML, that are important for the project, therefore I can't simply redirect them to the actual website. Creating the same HTML for all the different activities just seemes totally unnecessary.
Right now I'm a little lost on how to do this. I know I can't do this with HTML but could there be a way in js or do I need a backend to store all the links?

I would appreciate any help/ hint/implication on what I could do with that.

Comment: not sure why you can't simple use iframes whith some js to exchange the source adress when clicking your buttons

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a query parameter from the main page to the next page. By reading the query param value in the next page you can render the actual page in a container/iframe.

Main page: example.com/

Next Page: example.com/?actualPage=website1

Comment: It sounds pretty good, but I don't really get what you mean. So let's say I have the button and the href link I would give the button would be the one that you refer to as "next page" , so it would say "html-page_I-want-to-get-to/website-that-goes-into-iframe"?

Comment: yes..the parameter for the next website can be passed as a query parameter (html-page_I-want-to-get-to/?page=website-that-goes-into-iframe) or via the route parameter (html-page_I-want-to-get-to/website-that-goes-into-iframe). If you pass it via the route param, you need to handle this url pattern using your web server/backend to as to identify if the route parameter represents some directory, api of your application or it is the identifier of the website that goes in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use a Javascript templating engine. That would allow you to reuse the same HTML page with different content.

Note: Many of templating engines use NodeJS, however, if you want to just use Javascript, you can write something similar from scratch using pure JS or with the help of [JQuery](https://jquery.com/).